# Laravel new controller method doesn't work

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

When I create a new function in the controller for some reason it does not work. When I set the code from this function(getUnitsNotIn) to another function(index), that code works.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

My UnitsController.php action

```
public function index(){
    $items = Unit::select('parent_id')->where('parent_id','!=',NULL)->get()->toArray();
    return Units::whereNotIn('id',$items)->get();
}

public function getUnitsNotIn(){
    $items = Unit::select('parent_id')->where('parent_id','!=',NULL)->get()->toArray();
    return Units::whereNotIn('id',$items)->get();
}
```

My api.php

```
Route::apiResource('/units', 'UnitController');
Route::get('/units/notIn', 'UnitController@getUnitsNotIn');
```

In short, any new controller function that I make will not work. I tried to make a new controller and the same thing happens.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: `UnitController@getUnits` does not match the function name `getUnitsNotIn`. Is this a typo?

Comment: place your custom routes above your resource route

Comment: My mistake, when I wrote this post, forgot to put the real name of the function.

Comment: @dbudimir Have you used `show()` function  in the API controller?

Comment: @MrEvers Works this way, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because of `apiResource()`. Resource route assumes `/units/{id}`. so when you call `/units/notIn` route assume `notIn` as `id` And Action call `show()`

You need to use a different name.

```
Route::get('/un/notIn', 'UnitController@getUnitsNotIn');
```

**Verb**,       **path** ,          **action** ,      **route name**

`GET`    `/units/{id}`     `show`      `units.show`

Comment: Yes, I use the show () function in Api controller, this helped me, thanks

Comment: @dbudimir If you have used `show()` method otherwise path changes not required.
You only move route above `apiResource()`

Answer (score 1):

Change this to

```
Route::get('/units-notIn', 'UnitController@getUnitsNotIn');
```

You define a resource controller so here in units/notin,notin define a id so
it call your show function default.

Comment: My mistake when I edited the post, enrolled Id instead of In, in any case helped me your comment because I saw that I need to change the path because I use show function in API Controller